# OpenGL For loop (Random moon generation)

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm creating a 3d solar system in OpenGL for a university project and I've come to the point where I have to generate moons. Now generating a moon that orbits a planet is simple enough but I'm trying to create a loop that will generate the amount of moons I tell it too, and at random positions around the planet so the orbit for all of them is different.

```
for(int count = 0; count < 5; count ++)
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glTranslated (rand() % 8+8, 0.0, 0.0); //FIRST 
    glRotated((GLdouble) spin, 1.0, 70, 0.0);
    glutSolidSphere(0.8, 20, 10);
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

This is what I've come up with, however It appears to be creating the moons over and over. It creates the amount I specify but constantly re-creates them. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Of course it is recalculating the moons' positions over and over again. Calling rand() will give you a random number, it'll be different everytime. How about you calculate all moons' positions once at the start of your program and store their translations in some array. Then you use the values from your array inside your for-loop.

Comment: I will give that a go, seems simple enough. thanks very much

Comment: We've been given this specifically and told to use OpenGL, not an engine. but thanks for the input

Answer (score 3):

You should store the position of you moon when they are created and update this position when they rotate around their planet.

Your code, as it's currently written, will create a random Translate every time it is executed.

So to make it simple, add a process that creates moons, one that updates the moons to rotate around their planet (you probably already have a piece of code that handles rotation around the star?) and then render the updated solar system.

Answer (score 0):

Do an `srand(0)` before the `for`-loop so you get the same sequence of random numbers each time.

Comment: This has major implications which is beyond the positioning of his moons, in addition to requiring to recompute positions every time...

Answer (score 0):

You should probably create a structure or class like:

```
struct Moon
{
    float x, y, z;
    float rotAngle;
};
```

(*Make it as complex as you need it to be*)

Create the needed amount of objects (use array/list/...), initialize their values before the render loop.

And in the render loop, loop through all of those objects, update (*if you need?*) and display using their values.

Answer (score 0):

> however It appears to be <s>creating</s> *drawing* the moons over and over.

FTFY. OpenGL *is not* a scene graph. You do not generate a scene with it, that's somehow stored internally and presented to the user on demand. OpenGL is a *drawing* API. If you call drawing code in the animation loop, but always draw with some new random, parameters, things will jump around.

The solution: You need a scene graph. In you case a simple list where you store the initial parameters does suffice. If you want to spice it up, you could also determine the correct orbital velocity for a given distance from the planet of a given mass.